# Django - 'object is not iterable' error but there are no iterations on my object

Tags: django

I have a Model called Request with a Many-To-One model relationship where a User can have multiple Request objects. A Request is a custom made painting Model with many fields.

I am just trying to isolate the specific Request object the User clicked on and show it on a separate template called 'requestcarousel'. I am not running any for loops on the object so I am not sure why I am getting an 'object is not iterable' error. I've tried to use filter instead of get which doesn't give an error but none of the objects are being shown

Here is my view:

```
def requestcarousel(request, pk=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        allRequests = Request.objects.filter(requested_user=request.user.pk)
        requestedPaintings = allRequests.get(pk=pk)
        context = {
            'requestedPaintings': requestedPaintings,
        }
    return render(request, "requestcarousel.html", context)
```

Here is requestcarousel.html:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}
{% static "images" as baseUrl %}
{% block request_carousel_content %}
    {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
    <!-- START CAROUSEL -->
    <div class="card">
        <!-- Title -->
        <div class="container p-2">
            {% if requestedPaintings %}
                {% if LANGUAGE_CODE == 'ja' %}
                <div class="card-title p-3">
                    <h4>{{requestedPaintings.name}} </h4>
                </div>
                {% else %}
                <div class="card-title p-3">
                    <h4>{{requestedPaintings.english_name}} </h4>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- REQUEST IMAGE UPLOAD START -->
        {% if requestedPaintings %}
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded" id="myCarousel" style=" margin: 0 auto !important;">
                {% if requestedPaintings.painting %}
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="slide-content">
                            <img src="{{requestedPaintings.painting.url}}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>            
                {% else %}
                <!-- skip it -->
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <!-- add dimensions to painting -->
        <div class="container p-2">
            {% if requestedPaintings %}
                <div class="painting_description gallery-item text-center">
                    {% if LANGUAGE_CODE == 'ja' %}
                        <p class="text-center"  id="carousel_long_desc" style="font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif !important;">{{requestedPaintings.cm_size}} (センチ） <br> {{requestedPaintings.in_size}}（インチ) </p>
                        <p id="carousel_long_desc" >{{requestedPaintings.long_description}} </p>
                    {% else %}
                        <p class="text-center" id="carousel_long_desc" style="font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif !important;">{{requestedPaintings.cm_size}} (cm) <br> {{requestedPaintings.in_size}} (in)</p>
                        <p id="carousel_long_desc" >{{requestedPaintings.english_long_description}} </p>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="text-end">

            <!-- START REQUEST SOLD LABEL, PRICE DISPLAY, BUY BUTTON -->
            {% if requestedPaintings.is_sold is True %}
                <div class="container">
                    <p class="p-1 mt-1 fw-bold text-light rounded"style="background-color: rgb(255, 73, 73); font-size:small; float: right;">SOLD</p>
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <!-- yen or dollar display-->
                <div class="card-text">
                    {% if request.user.account.country == 'JP' %}
                        <div class="jpy_currency" id="jpy-price-{{requestedPaintings.pk}}">
                            ¥{{requestedPaintings.price}}<p  id="carousel_long_desc">({% trans 'スタンド付き' %})</p>
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        <!-- initially show jpy -->
                        <div class="usd_currency" id="usd-price-{{requestedPaintings.pk}}">
                            ${{requestedPaintings.dollar_price}}<p id="carousel_long_desc">({% trans 'スタンド付き' %})</p>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% if requestedPaintings.final_request is True %}
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info text-dark" 
                    href="/../{{LANGUAGE_CODE}}/checkout/{{requestedPaintings.id}}">
                    {% trans '購入する' %}
                </a>
            {% else %}
            {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The error is happening on this line in my views.py 
`return render(request, "requestcarousel.html", context)`

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/lctec/Desktop/kagprodrepo/repo/Art_Gallery_App/views.py", line 306, in requestcarousel
    return render(request, "requestcarousel.html", context)
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 62, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 157, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 322, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/lctec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 193, in render
    values = list(values)

Exception Type: TypeError at /ja/requestcarousel/6
Exception Value: 'Request' object is not iterable
Raised during: Art_Gallery_App.views.requestcarousel
Request information:
USER: crandy9
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Okay I posted it. Django is saying that the exception happened on the line in my views.py: "return render(request, "requestcarousel.html", context)"  but it doesn't make any sense

Comment: Is there anything related to `requestedPaintings` in your `index.html`? Also why do you call it `requestedPaintings` (plural) if it's meant to be a single instance?

Comment: **change  :** 

     requestedPaintings = allRequests.get(pk=pk)

**to :** 

     requestedPaintings = allRequests.filter(pk=pk)

Comment: Error happens when `ForNode` class called. Here is `for` loops in your template. Check included templates to find it: `{% extends "index.html" %}` and `{% block request_carousel_content %}`